# ASP.Net default login Email Confirmation without MVC

Tags: asp.net

My problem is that I have started a project, a web application. My last requirement is that the sign up email should be verified (send a confirmation email). I was checking google, but all I can see are samples using MVC, but the problem is that I have started mine not using it. Is there a way for me to send email verification using the default log in of asp.net without MVC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose you are using **ASP.NET Web Forms**. [Here](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/overview/security/create-a-secure-aspnet-web-forms-app-with-user-registration-email-confirmation-and-password-reset) are described basic steps you should implement using the ASP.NET Identity membership system.

Comment: @Katherine, Great! Consider [accepting](http://i.stack.imgur.com/QpogP.png) the answer if it helped.